# Why does the Plot not work?

Tags: plotting

this is the Funktion `lns`

```
lns = 10 Log[10^lnsij/10]
lnsij = lwsinst - dsai - rijref - 10 Log[si/10] - 10 Log[10/4]
dsai = 10 Log[(2 Pi mi 2.2 10^-ri/10)/(1.2041 343.2 tsi \[Delta]i)]
rijref = rij + 10 Log[10/ss]
rij = ri/2 + dri + rj/2 + drj + kij + 10 Log[ss/(1 lij)]
lwsinst = lwsc - dci
dci = 10 Log[(ys^2 + yi^2)/(ys Abs[yi])]
lwsc = (10 Log[vf^2/(1/10^12)])/ys
ys = vf/fb
vf = Sqrt[phm/Abs[1/yhm]]
fb = Sqrt[plm/Abs[ylm]]
```

Next step is to Deduce after the Parameters, which gives me the `Out[12] to Out[24]` what I need later.

```
D[lns, ri]
D[lns, rj]
D[lns, kij]
D[lns, yi]
D[lns, phm]
D[lns, ylm]
D[lns, plm]
D[lns, yhm]
D[lns, si]
D[lns, mi]
D[lns, tsi]
D[lns, \[Delta]i]
D[lns, lij]
```

Before we get to the Problem i show you how I write  Values down in a List

```
ri = {53, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
rj = {53, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
kij = {22, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
yi = {7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18}
phm = {(10^-7), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
ylm = {(-7), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16}
plm = {(10^-7), 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14}
yhm = {14, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}
si = {7.37}
ss = {9.36}
sf = {7.52}
mi = {24}
tsi = {0.1, 1, 2, 3}
\[Delta]i = {1}
dri = {1}
drj = {1}
lij = {1}
```

NOW, the problem

next Step is to Plot the Determination

(only the first Value in each List counts - right now)

```
ri = ri[[1]]
rj = rj[[1]]
kij = kij[[1]]
yi = yi[[1]]
phm = phm[[1]]
ylm = ylm[[1]]
plm = plm[[1]]
yhm = yhm[[1]]
si = si[[1]]
ss = ss[[1]]
sf = sf[[1]]
mi = mi[[1]]
tsi = tsi[[1]]
\[Delta]i = \[Delta]i[[1]]
dri = dri[[1]]
drj = drj[[1]]
lij = lij[[1]]
Plot[Out[12] \[CapitalDelta]ri, {\[CapitalDelta]ri, 0., 0.01}]
Plot[Out[13] \[CapitalDelta]rj, {\[CapitalDelta]rj, 0., 0.8}]
Plot[Out[14] \[CapitalDelta]kij, {\[CapitalDelta]kij, 0., 0.4}]
Plot[Out[15] \[CapitalDelta]yi, {\[CapitalDelta]yi, 0., 11}]
Plot[Out[16] \[CapitalDelta]phm, {\[CapitalDelta]phm, 0., 4 10^-9}]
Plot[Out[17] \[CapitalDelta]ylm, {\[CapitalDelta]ylm, 0., 4 10^-9}]
Plot[Out[18] \[CapitalDelta]plm, {\[CapitalDelta]plm, 0., 4 10^-9}]
Plot[Out[19] \[CapitalDelta]yhm, {\[CapitalDelta]yhm, 0., 11}]
Plot[Out[20] \[CapitalDelta]si, {\[CapitalDelta]si, 0., 0.2}]
Plot[Out[21] \[CapitalDelta]mi, {\[CapitalDelta]mi, 0., 0.5}]
Plot[Out[22] \[CapitalDelta]tsi, {\[CapitalDelta]tsi, 0., 0.004}]
Plot[Out[23] \[CapitalDelta]\[Delta]i, {\[CapitalDelta]\[Delta]i, 0., 
  0.01}]
Plot[Out[24] \[CapitalDelta]lij, {\[CapitalDelta]lij, 0., 0.01}]
```

Unfortunally
it doesnt work, I got no Plot for the Parameters `yi,ylm,yhm` on `Out[62],Out[64],Out[66]`
I also tryed `Table` to get some data points,  for example `yi`

```
{0.`, -108.54490223434316` (Sqrt[2]/7 - (3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(
    7 Sqrt[2])), -217.0898044686863` (Sqrt[2]/7 - (
    3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(7 Sqrt[2])), -325.6347067030294` (Sqrt[
    2]/7 - (3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(
    7 Sqrt[2])), -434.1796089373726` (Sqrt[2]/7 - (
    3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(7 Sqrt[2])), -542.7245111717158` (Sqrt[
    2]/7 - (3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(
    7 Sqrt[2])), -651.2694134060588` (Sqrt[2]/7 - (
    3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(7 Sqrt[2])), -759.814315640402` (Sqrt[
    2]/7 - (3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(
    7 Sqrt[2])), -868.3592178747452` (Sqrt[2]/7 - (
    3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(7 Sqrt[2])), -976.9041201090882` (Sqrt[
    2]/7 - (3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(
    7 Sqrt[2])), -1085.4490223434316` (Sqrt[2]/7 - (
    3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(7 Sqrt[2])), -1193.9939245777746` (Sqrt[
    2]/7 - (3 Derivative[1][Abs][7])/(7 Sqrt[2]))}
```

Maybe there is a Problem i cant see...
thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Set computed values to a symbol and use the symbol. Relying on `Out` numbers is bad because they are not guaranteed to be fixed.

Comment: For "Plot Out[62]" immediately after that line I inserted a line {...arguments of previous line...} to show me exactly what you are trying to plot. I think that shows me that you are trying to plot  the derivative of Abs[]. Mathematica isn't going to do that and that is why it fails to show anything. I would use the exact same trick for your other two plots and see if that tells you why you are not seeing plots. IF that trick doesn't work then the next more powerful trick is to replace Plot with Table and see some of the data points. One of those two methods will usually explain the problem.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi 
What do you mean by Symbols?
Instead of using the `out` i also tryed `D[lns,ri],D[lns,rj],D[lns,...` with the same result.

Comment: It's really difficult to go through your codes. My guess is that the problem is with derivative of `Abs` - I don't think it is well defined. Try using `Sqrt[x^2]` in place of `Abs[x]` when you need to take a derivative.

Comment: @Sumit

Thank you very much, now it workes.